# Are there any advanced proficiency tests for Standard Chinese (CEFR C1/C2)?

Tags: chinese, exams, certifications

HSK or Hanyu Shuiping Kaoshi is the PRC's official Chinese language proficiency test for non-native speakers of Standard Chinese. Hanban has published a [mappping](http://english.hanban.org/node_8002.htm) between the six HSK levels and the six levels of the [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages). For example, they claim that HSK 4 corresponds to CEFR level B2 and that HSK 6 corresponds to CEFR level C2.

However, as the "Fachverband Chinesisch" of the German-speaking countries has pointed out, [this mapping is erroneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanyu_Shuiping_Kaoshi#Estimates_of_equivalent_CEFR_levels). HSK4 actually corresponds (roughly) to CEFR level A2 and HSK 6 corresponds only with B2.

Hence, my question: are there any **proficiency tests for Standard Chinese that go beyond CEFR B2** and that cover at least level C1?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There are proficiency tests for Standard Chinese that go beyond B2 and that cover at least level C1.

The DLPT V offers assessments of High Level Language Proficiency. It has been 25+ years since I last took the DLPT. I am uncertain how openly it is offered.

The Defense language Institute Foreign Language Center offers an (Open to the Public) Online Diagnostic Assessment(ODA) also. The ODA is open to the public as are the GLOSS language resources.  You will need to register; however, you will not receive spam lol.  see at ODA(dot)DLIFLC(DOT)EDU

PLEASE NOTE THE ILR (Inter-agency Language Round-table) scale is used and is thoroughly explained.

Also **Language Testing International** [LTI](https://www.languagetesting.com/certifications-tests/certifications) offers assessments using using ACTFL certified raters, and a score assigned against either the ACTFL or the ILR scale.  ILR Certifications information can be seen under the pull down menu "CERTIFICATIONS FOR INDIVIDUALS", select mandarin, then select the "Federal Government Contractors & Employees with ILR requirements" test option to obtain further information. The services are open to all. Pricing for Active Federal Employees and Contractors may qualify for the GSA Pricing Schedule, otherwise you must accept regular price.